# Strange behavior of loss function in an implementation of TensorFlow matrix factorization model for recommendation system

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, recommendation-engine

Current implementation of recommendation system use TF 1.8 and [WALS](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.8/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/factorization/WALSMatrixFactorization) algorithm. The model was trained using self.fit(input_fn=input_fn) and ML Engine with run time version 1.8. Data set was formed following [example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/training-data-analyst/blob/master/courses/machine_learning/deepdive/10_recommend/wals.ipynb) using tensorflow.train.Example(...) Extraction from training logs shown below.

[image: Extraction from training logs]

The fit was performed with some default parameters. The loss value did decreased on second evaluation. However **loss** did not changed after that. The final Root weighted squared error (rwse) in this training became 0.126.

Hyperparameter tuning was performed later and the best parameter set was used in the following training. The result of that training is shown below. 
[image: Training logs using best parameters from hyperparameter tuning]

Tree things to note here. First, the loss value at the beginning is lower than at later evaluation steps. Low value in the beginning most likely due to choice of parameters from the results of hyperparameter tuning. Increase of the loss value later on looks strange. Second, it’s unchanged loss value after second evaluation. This pattern remains the same while self.fit(input_fn=input_fn) is used for model training. Third, the final rwse in this training became 0.487 while during hyperparameter tuning with the same parameter set rwse=0.015.

The question is if anyone observed something similar? Is it possible to improve performance of the algorithm using WALSMatrixFactorization class and self.fit(input_fn=input_fn, steps=train_steps)?? Thanks in advance for your help.